# How to direct bitcoins from Triplemining to a wallet?

Tags: wallet, miner-configuration

I use Triplemining.com for the share site, GUIminer for the Miner, and Multibit for the wallet. I just got this configured. On the "Account" page of Triple mining, it says "change payout address", but I don't remember specifying one. I am wondering what I put in there to hook up my Multibit wallet to TripleMining.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think there isn't one specified, and when you generate coins, they just stay on the site's wallet.
Just take your bitcoin receiving address from Multibit and paste that to the "payout address"-field.